# Creation of report

Tags: reporting

I have a requirement to create a report, We have a case with record type say 'A' associated with account 'B' and with case close date. Now I need to retrieve all the cases opened against the account 'B' after the case close date using reports.

I tried with custom report type by using accounts and cases but unable to filter out the cases based on case close date.

Can someone please share any thoughts.

Comment: You want to find all cases for all Accounts opened after a case of record type A was closed on that Account?  This can't be done with OOB reports

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any details of what you have done,   but I will try to answer :

--- Edit ---

Sorry - I got your question wrong - as already pointed out by @crop1645 you can't do it using OOB reports as the report criteria expects a fixed value.

Comment: I have set filter as case record type = A and date range = this month and case status = closed I am able to see the closed case associated with respective account 'B', but based on case close date Now I need to get the list of cases opened against the respective account after this case close date .... 

Please let me know If the above details are not clear ..Thanks in advance !!!!!!